# HTML a tag causes wide spaces

Tags: php, html, css

I have a sentence in PHP that I've broken down into its word components using explode.

```
foreach ($words as $splitword)
{
    echo $splitword;
    /* echo "<a href = 'word.php?word=" . $splitword . "'>" . $splitword . "</a>"; */
    echo " ";
}
```

What I want to do is make each word clickable, so I echo each word followed by a space. Now, using the code you see above, everything looks fine and natural. However, if I uncomment the commented line, and comment out `echo $splitword;`, so that I'm now echoing links instead of just the word, things get ugly:

1. `echo " "` no longer works, I have to use `echo "&nbsp"`
2. The spaces are very large. Echoing each word without making it a link produces natural spacing, the way it should be. But when I start using the `a` tag followed by `&nbsp`, the spaces are about twice as wide.

Any idea why, and what a workaround is?

Comment: You can try add the space at the end of line, like:
`echo "<a href = 'word.php?word=" . $splitword . "'>" . $splitword . "</a> ";`

Comment: [I've recreated your example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mqndIV) (look at the *Output: HTML* pane), and it looks just fine for me in various browsers. If it doesn't in yours, then perhaps you have issues with your browsers default styling settings. If it *does*, then I suspect you have some css rules in the website you are working on, that causes whitespace to collapse.

Comment: I'm don't think you need to force `&nbsp;`s, but I think what @fireeyedboy and Fábio suggested seems the most likely. It does sound like you may have CSS that is being applied to the anchors. I would check for properties like `display`, `margin`, `padding`, `line-height`, `width`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo " "` does not work because you are writing HTML, which does not parse " ". 
You'll have to use `&nbsp;` like you already discovered.

The extra spacing could be your styling. Check your CSS. If you still don't find anything strange, add this to your CSS:

```
a { 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}
```